# Extra bytes are discarded when a packet > 512 bytes is received

Tags: c++, qt

I began using QT not so long ago and I'm making a small network application. I got some kind of bytes limitation issue for the packet size I can receive.

Here is the code I use to read the bytes:

```
void client::readyRead()
{
    QByteArray data;
    while(socket->bytesAvailable()){
        data.append(socket->readAll());
    }
    dataReceived(data);
    //emit dataToProcess(data);
}
```

It works fine, until I get a packet bigger than 512 Bytes. Once I pass that, the rest is not put in `data` and my program crashes. I used Wireshark and confirmed that the packet contains exactly 1024 Bytes and is not fragmented. From what I read here, the `while` loop should allow the program to read the whole packet.

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a minimal but complete example?  (more than what's posted now).  When others can compile and test what you have, help is far more likely.

Comment: (i) by default, wireshark defragment fragmented packets; (ii) to understand why your program crashes we need more code, most naives crashes come from misusing implicitly shared objects (such as QByteArray) in multithread applications; (iii) Qt is spelled Qt, not QT

Comment: The program crash because I commented out the error handling for the encryption keys parsing and decryption so it stop right when that append (to be able to confirm the packet size and contents of the buffers).

The crash is caused by an "half-a-key" tried to be decoded. (the rest of the key is in the rest of the packet.

Comment: `Received : 190 Bytes.
Received : 512 Bytes.
Received : 512 Bytes.
Got login signal!
Received : 512 Bytes.
Received : 512 Bytes.
Received : 512 Bytes. <== SHOULD BE 1024 Bytes.
Received key :  MIICCAKCAgEAsQYs.... (incomplete key => crash(normal))`

Comment: Is this a TCP or UDP stream? Where's your setup code? Why is your code relying on the size of the individual receives?

Comment: It's a TCP stream. When the program receive a packet, He put it in an array and parsed right after. The problem might be because the program expect a complete packet (I put a while loop and readAll to be sure to read it all). I have no problem on the server (using ACE instead of QT there).

Comment: @DestroyFX TCP is a *stream*, as you say yourself. It's not partitioned into packets, and one 'receive' does not necessarily "match" one 'send'. If you want packets, encode them yourself in the stream or use a packet-oriented protocol.

Comment: It's a bad practice to rely on packet sizes or read chunks size or both like you do. Your application protocol should be more structured, at less with an end-of-key separator you can wait for before decoding (like end-of-line in HTTP, SMTP, FTP and the like) or a record/markup oriented format (like TIFF, XML and the like). (and I repeat Qt is not spelled QT ;-))

Comment: Thanks for all answer, I will look into it later today.

Comment: Your program sees a stream of bytes. There are no packets in it. Packets exist on the wire, but at the time your program gets to read the data, they are gone. Your stream arrives in chunks, but chunk boundaries are unrelated to either packet boundaries or chunks that the other side is sending.